# How to compare values in soql query when field may have a different format

Tags: apex, soql, query

I don't know if there is a way to solve this, I couldn't find it.

I am importing a CSV file where I am to create an sObject for each line. The thing is, I have to do a query using a value present in the csv file, for example let's say `value = 2554543`. So, the query could be something like `[SELECT Id FROM sObject WHERE Custom_Field__c = value]`. BUT, the problem is , the values on that Custom_Field__c could be like this `2554543` or like this `2-5545-43`.

How can I query against that field? Is it possible to only compare the numbers and ignore the other characters? (I don't want to do `WHERE Custom_Field__c = '2554543' OR '2-5545-43'`)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation where we need to query for phone numbers, but the phone number field can vary greatly in how people choose to enter them.  `(321)555-1212` vs `321-555-1212` etc
I solved for that by creating a new field which I called "Phone Key" and in a trigger I strip all non-numeric characters and just store the 10-digit phone number `3215551212` which I then use for all queries.

```
obj.Phone_Key__c = ( String.isBlank(obj.Phone) ? null : obj.Phone.replaceAll('[^0-9]','') );
```

Comment: I understand what you did. This means Salesforce has no function to format right-hand side values on queries? I have no other choice than to create another field on my sObject (could be formula field or your approach) ?

Comment: @joacoiudica Correct - there is no way to do what you need directly in SOQL.